# show dialog when recyclerview is empty in a pager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, fragment

i'm working with 2 fragments that display data, inside a pager, my problem is : that i want to show a dialog when there is no data to show but once i'm on the one of the two fragments and both their content is empty two dialogs are shown.
I tried several methods but none of them worked for me.

here is my pager adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter { 

ArrayList<Fragment> pages = new ArrayList<>();


public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


    return pages.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pages.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return pages.get(position).toString();
}

public void addPage (Fragment f){
    pages.add(f);
}
}
```

both the fragments are similar so i'll show the code of one of them :

```
public class FragmentIng extends Fragment {
private View v;


public FragmentIng() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ing, null);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        Recycler_View_Adapter adapter = new Recycler_View_Adapter(personnes1, this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        int i = adapter.getItemCount();

    if ( i == 0  ){
        final NiftyDialogBuilder dialogBuilder= NiftyDialogBuilder.getInstance(this.getContext());
        dialogBuilder
                .withTitle("Employé")                                  //.withTitle(null)  no title
                .withTitleColor("#FFFFFF")                                  //def
                .withDividerColor("#11000000")                              //def
                .withMessage("Aucun employé à afficher")                     //.withMessage(null)  no Msg
                .withMessageColor("#FFFFFFFF")                              //def  | withMessageColor(int resid)
                .withDialogColor("#FFE74C3C")                               //def  | withDialogColor(int resid)
                .withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
                .withDuration(700)                                          //def
                .withEffect(Shake)                                         //def Effectstype.Slidetop
                .withButton1Text("Retour")                                      //def gone
                .withButton2Text("Annuler")                                  //def gone
                .isCancelableOnTouchOutside(true)                           //def    | isCancelable(true)
                //.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view,v.getContext())         //.setCustomView(View or ResId,context)
                .setButton1Click(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialogBuilder.cancel();
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Principale", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);



                    }
                })
                .setButton2Click(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"i'm btn2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialogBuilder.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }



    return v;

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Les Employés";
}

}
```

and this is my recyclerview adapter :

```
public class Recycler_View_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<View_Holder>{


List<Personne> personnes = Collections.emptyList();
Context context;

Dialog dialog;

public Recycler_View_Adapter(List<Personne> list, Context context) {
    this.personnes = list;
    this.context = context;
}

private Context getContext() {
    return context;
}


@Override
public View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    View_Holder holder = new View_Holder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(View_Holder holder, final int position) {



    holder.title.setText(personnes.get(position).nom_prenom);
    //holder.description.setText("Etage N° : "+personnes.get(position).etage+" à "+personnes.get(position).date.toDateTime());
    holder.occurence.setText(personnes.get(position).occurence+" / "+personnes.get(position).NbrDeJour);




    animate(holder);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
            return personnes.size();
}



@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
public void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final Animation animAnticipateOvershoot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce_interpolator);
    viewHolder.itemView.setAnimation(animAnticipateOvershoot);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could solve your problem by overriding [setUserVisibleHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) method.

You can add this to your second fragment on viewpager in order to know when the fragment becomes visible to user and then you can check if recyclerview is empty in order to show your dialog.

For example

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (this.isVisible()) {

            if ( i == 0  ){
             final NiftyDialogBuilder dialogBuilder=NiftyDialogBuilder.getInstance(this.getContext());
             dialogBuilder
            .withTitle("Employé")                                  //.withTitle(null)  no title
            .withTitleColor("#FFFFFF")                                  //def
            .withDividerColor("#11000000")                              //def
            .withMessage("Aucun employé à afficher")                     //.withMessage(null)  no Msg
            .withMessageColor("#FFFFFFFF")                              //def  | withMessageColor(int resid)
            .withDialogColor("#FFE74C3C")                               //def  | withDialogColor(int resid)
            .withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
            .withDuration(700)                                          //def
            .withEffect(Shake)                                         //def Effectstype.Slidetop
            .withButton1Text("Retour")                                      //def gone
            .withButton2Text("Annuler")                                  //def gone
            .isCancelableOnTouchOutside(true)                           //def    | isCancelable(true)
            //.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view,v.getContext())         //.setCustomView(View or ResId,context)
            .setButton1Click(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialogBuilder.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Principale", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);



                }
            })
            .setButton2Click(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"i'm btn2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialogBuilder.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
            }

    }
}
```